# Strange share editing behavior

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, troubleshooting, file-sharing

For a while now, I have had issues attempting to change the share properties for any file or folder on my computer. When I open up file properties, this is what I see:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/n9GB9V3.png]

I am able to edit these properties, even though I don't know the names.

Here's a part where I am having trouble. When I go to edit the owner (I am logged on as Administrator), it pops up with this dialog:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/VISgqVc.png]

I am completely unable to edit the Owner (Auditing shows the same dialog).

I have noticed some strange behavior lately as well: I cannot delete certain files that I just created; Visual Studio claims that my executable (that I am compiling) is opened, etc... Also, I have done some research, and I think that it is possible that my hard drive could be corrupt, or I might have changed a setting I shouldn't have, but I am not sure about those two possibilities.

Basic Info:
I am on a laptop.
Hard drive: Hitachi HTS545025B9A300
Computer age: 4 years

**So my question is this:**

What can I do to fix this problem, is their software I can download to fix this, or is there a setting/registry change I can make to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please use the inbuilt image upload facility to add images to your post to avoid link rot.

Comment: Thank you, I was unable to because I had less than 10 rep (sorry).

Comment: Can you upload them to imgur then - imgur is a preferred image supplier for awhile - [source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) if you use imgur a edit can easily be made to display image rather then referring to a 3rd party site